# How does one extend MEF to create objects based on a factory type provided as an attribute?

Tags: c#-4.0, mef

Consider the following existing classes which uses [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to compose `Consumer`.

```
public interface IProducer
{
    void Produce();
}

[Export(typeof(IProducer))]
public class Producer : IProducer
{
    public Producer()
    {
        // perform some initialization
    }

    public void Produce()
    {
        // produce something
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    [Import]
    public IProducer Producer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Consumer(IProducer producer)
    {
        Producer = producer;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
        Producer.Produce();
    }
}
```

However, the creation of `Producer` has become complex enough that it can no longer be done within the constructor and the default behavior no longer suffices.

I'd like to introduce a factory and register it using a custom FactoryAttribute on the producer itself. This is what I have in mind:

```
[Export(typeof(IProducer))]
[Factory(typeof(ProducerFactory))]
public class Producer : IProducer
{
    public Producer()
    {
        // perform some initialization
    }

    public void Produce()
    {
        // produce something
    }
}

[Export]
public class ProducerFactory
{
    public Producer Create()
    {
        // Perform complex initialization
        return new Producer();
    }
}

public class FactoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ObjectType
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public FactoryAttribute(Type objectType)
    {
        ObjectType = objectType;
    }
}
```

If I had to write the "new" code myself, it may very well look as follows. It would use the factory attribute, if it exists, to create a part, or default to the MEF to create it.

```
public object Create(Type partType, CompositionContainer container)
{
    var attribute = (FactoryAttribute)partType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (FactoryAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (attribute == null)
    {
        var result = container.GetExports(partType, null, null).First();
        return result.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        var factoryExport = container.GetExports(attribute.ObjectType, null, null).First();
        var factory = factoryExport.Value;
        var method = factory.GetType().GetMethod("Create");
        var result = method.Invoke(factory, new object[0]);
        container.ComposeParts(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

There are a number of articles how to implement a ExportProvider, including:

1. [MEF + Object Factories using Export Provider](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/10/mef-object-factories-using-export.html)
2. [Dynamic Instantiation](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator)

However, the examples are not ideal when

1. The application has no dependencies or knowledge of `Producer`, only `IProducer`. It would not be able to register the factory when the `CompositionContainer` is created.
2. `Producer` is reused by several applications and a developer may mistakenly forget to register the factory when the `CompositionContainer` is created.
3. There are a large number of types that require custom factories and it may pose a maintenance nightmare to remember to register factories when the `CompositionContainer` is created.

I started to create a ExportProvider (assuming this would provide the means to implement construction using factory).

```
public class FactoryExportProvider : ExportProvider
{
    protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition,
                                                          AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
    {
        // What to do here? 
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble understanding how to tell MEF to use the factory objects defined in the FactoryAttribute, and use the default creation mechanism if no such attribute exists.

What is the correct manner to implement this?  I'm using [MEF 2 Preview 5](http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/79090) and .NET 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of a **property export**:

```
public class ProducerExporter
{
   [Export]
   public IProducer MyProducer
   {
       get
       {
           var producer = new Producer();
           // complex initialization here
           return producer;
       }
   }
}
```

Note that the term *factory* isn't really appropriate for your example, I would reserve that term for the case where the importer wants to create instances at will, possibly by providing one or more parameters. That could be done with a **method export**:

```
public class ProducerFactory
{
   [Export(typeof(Func<Type1,Type2,IProducer>)]
   public IProducer CreateProducer(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2)
   {
       return new Producer(arg1, arg2);
   }
}
```

On the import side, you would then import a `Func<Type1,Type2,IProducer>` that you can invoke at will to create new instances.

Comment: The term factory is appropriate in my example as I am following the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#C.23). MEF would be the "client" of the factory to create objects. The question was geared towards how extend MEF to use this pattern.

Both techniques are doable, but raises the question who is responsible for managing the lifetime of the IProducer being created.  For reasons of maintenance, I'd avoid both.

Comment: @WernerStrydom: 1) about the lifetime: in my first suggestion, MEF takes care of the lifetime. In the second suggestion, you can let the func create `ExportLifetime<IProducer>` so that the importer has a way to signal that it is done with an instance. That's how the existing `ExportFactory` mechanism in MEF works. 2) I'm unsure what you mean by "reasons of maintenance". The solution you were considering still requires a special export provider to be set up with the container. My own suggestions do not require this.

Comment: Also, I just realized that you may not have been aware of MEF's [ExportFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807(v=vs.95).aspx) where the importer (not MEF itself) is the client, hence the confusion about the term "factory".

Comment: The solutions are intrusive. It requires that I change all my consumers. It breaks every assumption I make when I look at the object without MEF. When ProducerExporter.MyProducer returns an object, who owns it, who disposes of it? If a consumer calls ProducerFactory.CreateProducer, who owns it, who is disposing of it? How does one achieve reuse? What I'm trying to say is that is is really error prone, maintainers of a large code base, of which this is part, can get confused and do the wrong thing.

Comment: When I used Unity, I registered an IProducerFactory, an IProducer (which resolves the factory to create it) without having to change any of the consumers. The consumers assume the object managed by some external actor (as one assumes when an object is passed thru an constructor). I have many more consumers that producers, hence the resistance to change every consumer.

Comment: @WernerStrydom: I think you are misunderstanding the property export solution. It works exactly like a class export for the consumer: it **does not require any changes to the consumer** (you just import `IProducer`) and ownership works the same way (the container owns the object, and will dispose it if necessary).

Comment: I perfectly understood the property export solution.  I do have to change all my factories accordingly or introduce a bunch of additional classes to wrap the factory in a "MEF" standard way.  In my opinion, it is not really a solution when one utilizes abstract factories all over the system. It is simpler to not use MEF and instead use Unity or Castle.

Comment: Thank you for the time to answer the question. It seems to be the only viable alternative other than writing your own export provider, which everyone tells me is complex and difficult.  I decided to drop MEF and use Unity instead. Numerous extensions exists for Unity giving it the same plugin infrastructure as MEF.